# Results Combine Rows by Column 1 Then SUM by Column 2 into Total THEN Order by DESC

Tags: mysql, sum, multiple-columns

I have a database with 4 columns:

1. Location
2. Date
3. Team_Name
4. Score

I need the results page to SELECT AND combine "Team_Name" WHEN equal and SUM "Score" AS Total and only show the current month at an individual location "BW3Avon".

Here is my code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","*******_admin","g********1");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("x0kqgoub_bw3avonscore", $con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bw3avonscore WHERE MONTH(myDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bw3avonscore Team_Name ORDER BY Score DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['Team_Name'] . " " . $row['Score'];
echo "<br />";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  Team_Name, SUM(Score) totalScore
FROM    tableName
WHERE   Location = 'BW3Avon' AND
        MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP   BY Team_Name
```